# Apache2: Disable directory listing globally

Tags: list, apache2

I've a Debian WebServer running Apache2.
How can I disable directory listing, globally, for all websites?

Note: This should also overwrite possible settings of virtual hosts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue the following in you server terminal:

```
sudo a2dismod autoindex
service apache2 reload
```

After this all websites will have directory listing disabled.